# pyside Qt how do I find if an existing qmenu exists?

Tags: python, pyside

Sorry if this sounds like a simple question, if I have some code that generates a qmenu inside a qmenu (i.e. a file menu that has folders inside) I want to check if the folder already exists before adding a new one. I'm unable to find a way of querying the qmenus that already exist, what am I missing? I had assumed they were children of the current qmenu?

```
child_Item = self.getChildMenu(_parentQMenu, _folderStructure[0])
    if child_Item == None:
        newMenu=QtGui.QMenu("FolderName")
        _parentQMenu.addMenu(newMenu)
    else:
        newMenu=QtGui.QMenu("FolderName2")
        child_Item.addMenu(newMenu)
```

The `.getChildmenu` needs to return either nothing or the correct child, currently I'm not sure how to find that item, the `_parentQMenu` object must have a way of accessing the menu's that have already been added to it?

Comment: Every menu has an [associated action](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmenu.html#menuAction) that contains it, and it also has a [list of all the actions](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#actions) that are added to it.

Comment: An existing menu exists sort of by definition.

Comment: @ekhumoro A list of what's been added is exactly what I'm after, clearly this isn't the children (the children of my qmenu are always a single  qaction even when my menu has 100 entries)  and qList seems to only be in c++, I'm clearly missing something somewhere!

Answer (score 1):

Got it, sorry for the confusion :)

```
def getChildMenu(self, _parentQMenu, _childName):  
    for a in _parentQMenu.actions():
        if a.text() == _childName:
            return a.menu()
    return None
```